# Set SelectedValue of GridDropDownColumn

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I'm trying to set the value of a GridDropDownColumn in my RadGrid.
Note that my GridDropDownColumn is not in a template, just part of `<columns>`.

I'm using the InsertCommand event to do this as my whole experiment is around manipulating data in there.

Frontend:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server">
  <MasterTableView>
    <Columns>
       <telerik:GridDropDownColumn DataSourceID="MySource" DataField="RowId" UniqueName="RowId" ListValueField="id" ListTextField="Name" SortExpression="RowId" HeaderText="RowId" />
    </Columns>
  </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Backend:

```
protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Item is GridEditFormItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode) {
    GridEditFormItem editItem = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;
    DropDownList list = (DropDownList)editItem["GridDropDownColumn"].Controls[0];
    list.SelectedValue = HiddenFieldIdToSave.Value;
  }
}
```

This is giving me a rather nasty error though.

```
Unhandled exception at line 15, column 16485 in http://localhost:55555/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=;;System.Web.Extensions,+Version=4.0.0.0,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=31321323135:en-N:5924cf72drgdrg-a608a92942c5:ea597d4b:b25378d2;Telerik.Web.UI,+Version=2014.2.724.45,+Culture=neutral,+PublicKeyToken=121fae781awdawggcvb31-d2d2285652a6:fghfghfghf:58366029

0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Cannot find cell bound to column with unique name 'GridDropDownColumn'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why i was getting this error.

I had 2 dropdown lists which both hooked up on the same datasource, this caused a false value to be passed, this then caused my Insert/Update DataObjectMethod to fire the error.

Also my example was looking at the wrong UniqueName.

Answer (score 0):

In your backend C#, you're trying to access a column named `GridDropDownColumn`, but instead you should be using the row's `UniqueName` property, which you've set as `RowId`.  Try this:

```
protected void RadGrid1_InsertCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditFormItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditFormItem editItem = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;

        // Use the column's unique name as the accessor:
        DropDownList list = (DropDownList)editItem["RowId"].Controls[0];

        list.SelectedValue = HiddenFieldIdToSave.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, i changed it so im correctly targeting my RowId, however the same error still occurs.

Comment: You should update your code in your question then. How are you calling RadGrid1_InsertCommand and/or firing the InsertCommand event?

Comment: Hi DanM, i found out why i was getting this error even after using your suggestion. I had 2 dropdown lists which both hooked up on the same datasource, this caused a false value to be passed, this then caused my Insert/Update DataObjectMethod to fire the error. 
I have now fixed it and is problem free, thank you for the help.

Comment: You should post that as an answer and then accept it!